# I need to create a page or post hierarchy

Tags: posts, categories, pages

I am currently stuck and I need some advice ASAP. I am making a site for a client on which they need to have a sort of hierarchy like this

```
Carriers (Main Category or page)
-Level 1
   -Level 2
      -Level 3 (sometimes needed)
   -Level 2
   -Level 2
-Level 1
   -Level 2
   -Level 2
-Level 1
   -Level 2
-Level 1
```

I was thinking about doing it through parent and child apges but that would create a ton on empty pages which purpose would only be to hold the children.

I also though about doing it through post categories but I am not sure how to do that since the hierarchy isnt always consistent, some have 3 levels and others only one. Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would empty child pages be created?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to show the hierarchy in the menu, choose Appearance->Menus and build your hierarchy there by using Custom Links.

Use # for levels that don't need to have a page, but use a URL when you get to the bottom level (a page that has content).

[image]

You can then arrange them on the right then drag them to the right to create the hierarchy like this.

[image]

Another option would be to setup categories to replicate your hierarchy like this.

[image]

Comment: Yea I thought about that but no.... I need it to be like.

click one option on Level one >> shows next page level (click one option there) >> shows next page level (click another option there) >>> show final post with content

But some only have one level..... others have up to three.

Comment: Then you just need to make pages that contain the options to click on for the level.

Comment: I know that you said you didn't want to have pages that were only for holding the children, but I'm not sure what the problem is with that. Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Well the problem is that its ALOT! of child pages with children of their own...so thats my problem... I was thinking about doing it using child categories and posts but.... that would only work if it was always the same level of children

Comment: I think you'll have to either have TONS of pages or TONS of categories, the category approach will probably be the fastest way. You'll just need to create a category for every single level, (some categories will have more children that others) then assign your content pages to its respective category.